# How to iterate through int?

Tags: c++, iterator, int

I'm confused on how i can iterate through my int, and then put the result in a int vector.. I'm needing to do this for a game, help would be very much appreciated.. honestly, i have no idea how to make this function, that will iterate through int...

```
cout << "\n PLEASE ENTER A 4 DIGIT BINARY! OR PROGRAM WILL EXIT \n\n\t";
cin >> binaryCin;
evaluateNum(binaryCin);     

void MasterMind::evaluateNum(int &bin) {
    // Need to iterate through binarycin and then put it in a vector<int>..
}
```

Comment: So are you expecting 1010? Or 1234? Or 1 enter 2 enter 3 etc.?

Comment: What do you want in this vector of ints? Just the one number?

Comment: yea @Caperneoignis a 4letter binary

Comment: a vector of ints @cuniculus has 4 letters exactly

Comment: so if they enter 1010 like @Caperneoignis said, then what do you want to be in the vector of ints? {1, 0, 1, 0} ?

Comment: Exactly @cuniculus! I gtg sleep now, appreciate if you guys anwser, ill accept tommorow if any anwsers

Comment: Remember @cuniculus i dont want to change to string

Comment: Did we answer you question?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, since you can not use strings, I'll have to change my answer. So for the sac of speed. I'll use math. Zero is a bit of a problem, but just have an if statement to check place holder after the division, and just go from there. I'm sure there is a library you can use to make this easier, but it does not sound like you can use any of that, almost like this is homework. So we have to do it this way. Also, don't worry about the decimal place, since it is int it will trim the decimal spot off. soo 427 / 100 = 4.27 which in int will just be 4. I believe the compiler always truncates, if I'm wrong let me know.

```
void MasterMind::evaluateNum(int &bin)
{
    std::vector<int> numbers();
    int thousand,hundred,ten;
    int placeholder = 0;
    thousand = 1000;
    //bin = 4327
    placeholder = thousand / bin;
    //subtract the thousand position out of bin
    bin -= placeholder * thousand;
    numbers.push_back(placeholder);
    //now you have 327 
    //subtract the hundreds spot now
    hundred = 100;
    placeholder = hundred / bin;
    bin -= placeholder * thousand;
    numbers.push_back(placeholder);
    //now you have 27 now tens
    ten = 10;
    placeholder = ten / bin;
    bin -= placeholder * ten;
    //now you have just 7 in bin and 2 in place holder
    numbers.push_back(placeholder);
    numbers.push_back(bin);
}
```

thats how you pull apart the ints that were passed in by the user. You should make a check to ensure the number is not to big. Youll need to add a check/condition, for 0, and just drop out the place holder if the value is 0. so instead of `bin -= placeholder * ten`. it would be `bin -= ten`; or just skip it completely, I don't remember if C++ handles 026 as 026 or just 26. Run it once with a zero and you'll have your answer.

Comment: i dont want to change to string.. thats the point. igtg sleep now

Answer (score 0):

This would be better than doing fixed math based calculation

```
 void MasterMind::evaluateNum(int &bin) {
        int n = bin;
        int i=0;
        vector<int> arr;
        while(n!=0){                    // loop will work for any size of binary number
            int tmp = n & 1;
            arr.push_back(tmp);
            n>>=1;
            i++;
        }
        std::reverse(arr.begin(),arr.end());  // since loop will give you reverse
}
```

And I don't see any string that you'd want "not modified" but if u were refering to bin then it won't be modified using extra variable